# create gulp task for rewireify

Tags: javascript, gulp

trying to put this into a watch task?

```
browserify -e test/spec/suite.js -t reactify -t rewireify -o test/spec/bundle.js
```

My gulp file is this currently:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
requireDir = require('require-dir');

requireDir('./gulp-tasks');

gulp.task('default', ['browserify','css','karma'], function () {
gulp.watch('../App/src/**/*.js', ['browserify']);
 gulp.watch('../App/src/**/*.css', ['css']);
gulp.watch('../App/src/tests/**/*.js', ['rewireify']);
gulp.watch('../App/src/tests/**/*.js', ['karma']);
});

gulp.task('production', ['react', 'css']);
```

rewireify.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
rewireify = require('rewireify');

gulp.task('css', function () {
gulp.src([
    './App/src/tests/**/*.js'
])
    .pipe(concat('bundletest.js'))
    .pipe(rewireify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('test/spec/bundle.js'));
});
```

when I run my gulp task I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ignore' of undefined
    at rewireify (d:\Source\Workspaces\\node_modules\rewireify\lib\index.js:12:20)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (d:\Source\Workspaces\Call Parents\DEV\CG.CallParents.Web\Areas\Beta\gulp-tasks\rewireify.js:10:15)
at module.exports (d:\Source\Workspaces\\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (d:\Source\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (d:\Source\\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (d:\Source\Workspaces\\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
at C:\Users\matthew.harris\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

Anyone know how I can get it working?

Answer (score 0):

The key point to remember is that rewireify (love the name) is a *transform*:

> The most powerful feature in Browserify are [source transforms](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#list-of-source-transforms). A source transform is a stream injected between the resolved module and the content that is returned. A simple use case for using a source transform is compiling CoffeeScript to JavaScript.

http://blakeembrey.com/articles/2013/09/introduction-to-browserify/

Any way, my suggestion is to separate the `gulp-concat` part into its own task then create a rewireify task which you will call after:

```
gulp.task("build-functional", function () {
    return browserify('some-gulp-concatenated.js', {})
        .transform(rewireify, rewireifyOptions)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(gulp.dest('test/spec/bundle.js'))
}
```

Check out [here](https://github.com/i-like-robots/rewireify/blob/master/test/build.js) for another example.